# Supervised or unsupervised

Tags: neural-network, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

In case when I am trying to solve classification problem with neural network and classes in a dataset are calculated with k-means. Is it supervised or unsupervised learning?

Answer (score 0):

This may fall into the class of heuristic approach to [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning).